# invalid conversion from *void to *int [-fpermissive] using malloc(sizeof())

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory

I'm writing a program that calculates the greatest common denominator of two numbers, but i'm getting problem with `malloc` function and pointers. Actually it's clear how the stack and the heap segments work in the memory and why. But yet i'm not yet able to understand when declaring a pointer and using `malloc` is functional or not, is necessary or not, in a program. here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *calcolaDivisori(int);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int foundCounter = 0;
    int i,j,s1,s2;
    int n1,n2;
    int mcd = 1,mcm;
    int *pn1,*pn2;
    int d1[100],d2[100];

    // INPUT dei due interi

    printf("Inserisci il primo numero :");
    scanf(" %d", &n1);
    printf("\nInserisci il secondo numero :");
    scanf(" %d", &n2);

    // calcolo divisori del primo e del secondo numero e li assegno ai relativi array

    pn1 = calcolaDivisori(n1);
    if (!pn1) return 1;
    pn2 = calcolaDivisori(n2);
    if (!pn2) return 1;

    for (i=0;i<n1;i++) {
        d1[i] = pn1[i];
    }

    for (i=0;i<n2;i++) {
        d2[i] = pn2[i];
    }

    free(pn1);
    free(pn2);

    // confronto i divisori e calcolo il MCD

    s1 = sizeof(d1) / sizeof(int);
    s2 = sizeof(d2) / sizeof(int);

    for(i=0; i<s1; i++) {
        for (j=foundCounter; j<s2;j++) {
            if (d1[i] == d2[j]) {
                mcd*= d1[1];
                foundCounter = j+1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nIl minimo comune divisore e' : %d", mcd);

    return 0;
}

int *calcolaDivisori(int num) {
    int i;
    int *a = malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    if (!a) return NULL;
    for (i=2;i<num;i++) {
        if (num%i == 0) {
            num/=i;
            a[i-2]=i;
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

I get the error in the title when is run the command :

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: You should only get this warning if you are compiling your code as C++. A C compiler will not give this warning.

Comment: @kaylum - `#include <iostream>` another giveaway I'd say.

Comment: @DanAllen Yeah you're right. I missed that and only saw the `C` tag. @Ghislo please fix up your tags as it appears you are writing C++ code and not C code (if that is indeed your intention).

Comment: `#include <iostream>` delete this line.

Comment: You've tagged the question C but used a couple of C++ constructs. You need to decide whether you're trying to write a C or C++ program. The advice in this area is quite different between the two.

Comment: This is `C` code an not `C++`. Use a proper compiler.

Comment: @Michi `#include <iostream>` is not C code

Comment: @M.M You right, but this is not part of he's problem. And I see now that the OP doesn't respond at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast:

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(num * sizeof(int));
```

Because there's no implicit conversion from `void*` to `type *` in C++.

Note that this cast is not required in C and could potentially be [dangerous](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html) to do so in C.

Except for `#include <iostream>`, nothing in your code is C++. So remove it and compile it with a C compiler and you wouldn't need this cast.

Comment: Since this is C++, may as well use `static_cast<>`, makes it harder to mistake for C, and reminds the programmer to remove the cast if the code is copy-pasted into an actual C source. Or better yet, remove the malloc altogether in C++, using an `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Medinoc Yes, I agree your suggestion. But I am not sure if it's really C++. I thought of editing the tag to C++. But it really seems to be C code with the exception of including `<iostream>` (and hence OP compiles it as C++).

Comment: You shouldn't use malloc in C++ programs so there is no need to ponder the cast in the first place. Mixing malloc/free while everything else in C++ uses the non-compatible `new`/`delete`, is a very stupid idea which will only cause bugs.

Comment: The OP removed the `C++` tag, there is no code which suggest using of `C++`, but `C`. I think the only problem is the compiler, he use a `C++` compiler.

Comment: @Lundin Keep in mind though, don't replace the malloc() with a `new[]` if you can't see the matching free() to replace with a `delete[]` (here, we can see the free() in the main function).

Comment: @Michi good eye. Ooh, maybe it's a POSIX platform and the file is saved with a capital `.C` extension?

Comment: perfect answer still works in 2022