# malloc error: a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int **"

Tags: c++, malloc

I have tried:

```
int** thread_args = malloc(24);
```

and

```
int** thread_args = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 3);
```

but I keep getting the error message.

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you compiling with a C++ compiler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid conversion from \*void to \*int \[-fpermissive\] using malloc(sizeof())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286287/invalid-conversion-from-void-to-int-fpermissive-using-mallocsizeof)

Comment: @tkausl yes. I am new to C++, and I never used to get this error in C99

Comment: @Isaac`malloc` is `C` specific. use `new` in CPP.

Comment: Well you should tag C++ then, not C. This is valid in C but not in C++. You have to decide which language you want to program in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does C++ require a cast for malloc() but C doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477741/why-does-c-require-a-cast-for-malloc-but-c-doesnt)

Comment: @Isaac See Wikipedia article [Compatibility of C and C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: You should not use malloc in C++

Comment: You forgot to try `int** thread_args = new int*[3];`, which is the C++ way. Next stop on the C++ train: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> thread_args(3);`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use C++ compiler, you may need to cast the result of malloc:

`int ** th_args = (int**)malloc(24)`

or simply use operator `new`.

If you use a `C` compiler, then... I am not sure of why this error is thrown

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're supposed to use `static_cast<>` in C++ (or an existing container type, really).